# Centering div margin top and margin bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get margin-top and margin-bottom to center my `<div>`. This JavaScript, which I wrote, works. However, if the site is cached once, <kbd>CTRL+F5</kbd> refresh causes the script to receive a wrong `clientHeight`. Refreshing second time, retrieves the correct `clientHeight`.

I've tried using `window.load` and this works. However, it is so slow that the `<div>` loads and after 2 seconds, it shifts to the middle.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var height = $(window).height();
  var clientHeight = document.getElementById('account-wall').clientHeight;
  var calc_height = (height - clientHeight) / 2;
  document.getElementById("account-wall").style.marginTop = calc_height + 'px';
  document.getElementById("account-wall").style.marginBottom = calc_height + 'px';
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).load(function() {
    var height = $(window).height();
    console.log(height);
    var clientHeight = $('.account-wall').height();
    console.log(clientHeight);
    var calc_height = (height - clientHeight) / 2;
    document.getElementById("account-wall").style.marginTop = calc_height + 'px';
    document.getElementById("account-wall").style.marginBottom = calc_height + 'px';
  });
</script>
```

Comment: please give a link to jsfiddle or upload the code here

Comment: As an alternative, I believe you can centre a div vertically or horizontally using standard CSS and setting margin:50%. It might be an easier solution. Google for `css vertical  alignment in div` or similar.

Comment: Please add the `html` and `css` too. Or, in short, please create a [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or [bin](http://jsbin.com)

Answer (score 0):

Use a resize event since you need it to be centered even if the window.height changes. To make sure it is centered from the beggining use .resize() to trigger the event.

```
$(window).on('resize', function(event){
  var height = $(window).height();
  console.log(height);
  var clientHeight = $('.account-wall').height();
  console.log(clientHeight);
  var calc_height = (height - clientHeight)/2;
  document.getElementById("account-wall").style.marginTop = calc_height+'px';
  document.getElementById("account-wall").style.marginBottom =         calc_height+'px';
}).resize();
```